# lapply and lme4 to calculate BLUEs with differing number of rows

Tags: r, lapply, lme4

I am trying to calculate the BLUEs for several columns using lapply and lme4. There are 2 replicates of 264 lines with rep and block information, as well as 4 phenotypes.

The simple function that I am using to extract the fixed effects is:

```
blues.rb <- function(traits, dat = ".") {
b<- as.data.frame(fixef(lmer(paste0(traits, "~ 0 + Lines + (1|rep) + 
(1|rep:block)"), data = dat)))
}
```

This is then run using:

```
pheno15$Lines <- as.factor(pheno15$Lines)
pheno15$rep <- as.factor(pheno15$rep)
pheno15$block <- as.factor(pheno15$block)

effectvars <- names(pheno15) %in% 
             c("block", "rep", "Lines", "year", "column", "row", "experiment_id")
traits <- colnames(pheno15[ , !effectvars])

blues2015<- as.data.frame(lapply(traits, blues.rb, dat = pheno15))
names(blues2015) <- traits
```

The error that I receive is:

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, 
check.names = TRUE,  : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 264, 262
```

I know that this is caused by the presence of missing values in the original data but I was hoping for a simple fix?

I tried to use

```
fixef(object, add.dropped = TRUE)
```

yet that doesn't change the results.

Here's a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7qri9eqfl7clhic/phenotypeQ.txt?dl=0) to the data:

Comment: I'm getting `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Taxa' not found` is there another column name that should take it's place?

Comment: No sorry, I renamed that column to lines so that I don't give away data I'm not supposed to. I'll edit the question

Comment: When I run it with `Lines` instead, it runs without error. I get values "0.1873296 -6.582604e-05 -0.02391832 -0.002139517" for columns "GRWT         MOIST        PTHT         HDDT"

Comment: The fixef() function should give you a value for every line, which is used as the Best Unbiased Linear Estimate

Comment: so you want to treat "Lines" as a factor and not a numeric

Comment: Yes, sorry I never realised that when I change the lines to numbers I should specify that it is a factor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is `tidyverse` solution.

Keep your results as a list, don't coherce to data.frame just yet:

```
blues2015<- lapply(traits, blues.rb, dat = pheno15)
```

Then add the appropriate column names with `map2()` similar to `mapply()` and get the rownames inserted as proper columns:

```
library(tidyverse)
blues2015 <- map2(blues2015, traits, ~ set_names(..1, ..2) %>%
                      rownames_to_column(var = "Line")) %>%
    reduce(full_join)
```

And finish with a `reduce(full_join)` to keep all rows for Lines and dodge that error because MOIST has two missing values.

```
head(blues2015)

    Line     GRWT  MOIST      PTHT      HDDT
1 Lines1 472.5796  9.135  86.55540  2.023394
2 Lines2 255.5317  8.770 107.42463 12.527692
3 Lines3 475.1308  8.965  95.47639 11.996619
4 Lines4 773.0695  8.995  89.57909  8.003491
5 Lines5 740.0130  9.200  89.55191  1.984823
6 Lines6 607.8674 10.335  91.55662 16.001055
```